# A RenderFlex overflowed by 1029 pixels on the right

Tags: flutter

How do I resolve the exception "A RenderFlex overflowed by 1029 pixels on the right."
I don't want the entire article to appear. I want it to appear in a nutshell. Why doesn't Maxlines work?

```
Widget buildTripCard(BuildContext context, int index){
    final trip = tripsList[index];
    return new Container(
      child: Card(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 0.0, bottom: 1.0),
                child: Row(children:<Widget>[Text(trip.title, style:new TextStyle(fontSize:24.0 )),Spacer()]),
              ),

              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 1.0,bottom: 16.0),
                child: Row(children: <Widget>[Text("Tarih ${DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy').format(trip.Date).toString()} --> ${DateFormat('HH:mm').format(trip.startDate).toString()} - ${DateFormat('HH:mm').format(trip.endDate).toString()}"),
                  Spacer()]),
              ),
              //Text(trip.endDate.toString()),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:16.0, bottom: 16.0),

                child: Row(
                  //mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[

                    Text(trip.summary,maxLines: 1,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),
                    SizedBox(height: 15.0,),
                    //Spacer()


                  ],

                ),
              )

            ],

          ),
        ),

      ),

    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your Text widget with an Expanded:

```
Expanded(child:Text(trip.summary,maxLines: 1,overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis),)
```